# org-mode: search by regular expression in file

Tags: org-mode

In org mode there is a way to create a link that will search for text in file./ For example:

```
[[./functions.pl::sub validate][sub validate]]
```

This will search for text "sub validate" in file "functions.pl". Unfortunately, there is another function in this file before "validate": sub validate_row.

And the search jumps to it. Can I set the regexp for "sub validate" so it jumped exactly to "validate"?

Answer (score 2):

The docstring for `org-link-search` says:

> Search for a search string S.
>
> If S starts with "#", it triggers a custom ID search.
>
> If S is enclosed within parenthesis, it initiates a coderef
>   search.
>
> If S is surrounded by forward slashes, it is interpreted as
>   a regular expression. [...]

So you can use something like:

```
[[./functions.pl::/sub validate[^_]/][sub validate]]
```

Comment: As soon as I put the bracket `[`, it stops interpreting it as a link.

Comment: Try editing it by typing  `C-c C-l` with point on it.

Comment: It worked, but now it gives me a buffer with occurrences of the regexp now. Is it possible to transfer me to the 1-st destination immediately?

Comment: Indeed it does jump to found position for simple string search, but present results with occur for a regexp search. Sadly, whitespace is ignored, otherwise we could do a string search on "sub validate " (including a trailing space).

Comment: If the opening brace { is on the same line, you can use [[./functions.pl::sub validate {][jump]].